# No internet connection in most kernels (18.04 LTS)

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I have recently updated to lts 18.04 and I couldn't get the amdgpu-pro drivers to work well in this version (intended for 16.04).
I have tried to downgrade the kernel multiple times but it still returns a error in dkms when installing the drivers (with kernel 4.4.0-040400-generic and 4.5.0-040500-generic) but when I try different kernels from other sources my pc doesn't detect my wired or wireless networks adapters (but it shows then when running `sudo lshw -c network`).

I appreciate any help you can give me with both problems

useful commands:

```
$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic                   4.15.0-20.21                                
amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-040400-generic                4.4.0- 
040400.201601101930                   amd64        Linux kernel image 
for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic                   4.4.0- 
112.135~14.04.1                       amd64        Linux kernel image 
for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic                    4.4.0- 
87.110~14.04.1                        amd64        Linux kernel image 
for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.5.0-040500-generic                4.5.0- 
040500.201603140130                   amd64        Linux kernel image 
for version 4.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP


$ sudo dpkg --list | grep linux-headers
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-040400                      4.4.0- 
040400.201601101930                   all          Header files related to 
Linux 
kernel version 4.4.0
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-040400-generic              4.4.0- 
040400.201601101930                   
amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.5.0-040500                      4.5.0- 
040500.201603140130                   
all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.5.0
ii  linux-headers-4.5.0-040500-generic              4.5.0- 
040500.201603140130                   
amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP


$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
RX packets 589  bytes 37175 (37.1 KB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 589  bytes 37175 (37.1 KB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


$ sudo lshw -c network
*-network UNCLAIMED       
description: Ethernet controller
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
version: 09
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f0304000-f0304fff memory:f0300000 
f0303fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
version: 01
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f7d00000-f7d03fff
```

gpu driver error:

```
WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel
```

(`clinfo` gives me a seg fault after the last attempt to install the drivers and after a reboot it changed to showing 0 devices)

note: I'm new to linux :D

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `sudo dpkg --list | grep linux-headers` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Start with installation of the proper kernel. Run `sudo apt install linux-generic` and reboot.

Comment: Since there is no internet connection it cannot run that successfully. And it tries to install the 4.15 kernel which is not native to de lts version 14 that is the one the gpu drivers are intended to be used in.